# How to obtain a reference to a list from the string name of the list in python

Tags: python, introspection

Assume I have a class with three lists as follows:

```
class Test_Class (): 
     a = [1,2,3]
     b = [4,5,6]
     c = [7,8,9]
```

I want to define a method in this class, lets call it get_list, such that if I pass the string name of the list, the method returns a reference to the list.     For example if I made a call like this:   `a_list = get_list('b')`.  Then type >> a_list, at a Python prompt, what would be returned would be [4,5,6].    How can I do this?

Comment: `tc = Test_Class(); getattr(tc, 'b');`

Comment: See the documentation for the `getattr` built-in function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: why dont use save as dict ? {'a' : [1,2,3]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to create a method in your class I suggest you can use the following.

```
class Test_Class (): 
    a = [1,2,3]
    b = [4,5,6]
    c = [7,8,9]
    def get_list(self,lstString):
        return getattr(obj, lstString)
obj = Test_Class()
print(obj.get_list('a'))
print(obj.get_list('b'))
print(obj.get_list('c'))
```

We have a function called `get_list()` which takes an argument `lstString` - the list you want to receive. Then we make use of `getattr(ourObject,variableName)`.

output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```